# How dns.resolve() does in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, dns

I had known that `dns.lookup` will invoke `uv_getaddrinfo`, and read some files in order, but I don't know that the implements of `dns.resolve`.

Comment: Formatting/Highlighting

Comment: Could you say some details,please